# Keeping focus on first input for each tab

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some wizard tabs that each contain form elements. I want to focus on the first form element for each tab. How do I keep focus for only the visible elements. EG: I do not want my first hidden tab to be focused when I have navigated to the next tab form.

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/kdWT8/

This does not seem to work?

```
$('.focus:first:not(:hidden)').focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

You do it the other way around:

```
$('.focus:not(:hidden):first').focus();
```

Right now you're getting the first element with the class `.focus`, which is of course hidden, then you filter on visible elements only, and that leaves you with nothing?
You need to get the visible elements, and then get the first one.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kdWT8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
$(document).find('.focus').filter(':visible').eq(0).focus();
```

With the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdWT8/4/)**

I think chaining is more readable than sizzle selectors; here it reads *"find all the elements with class focus, filter only the ones that are visible, take the first one and give it focus"*